# NameError passed arguement to constructor of class is not defined

Tags: python-2.7

Why am i getting `NameError: name 'height' is not defined`? Even When i have passed the argument to the constructor of the class Rectangle?

```
class Rectangle(object):

    class Point(object):
        def __init__(self, x, y):
            self.x=x
            self.y=y

        def getx(self):
            return self.x

        def gety(self):
            return self.y

    def __init__(self, height, width, point):
        self.width=width
        self.height=height
        self.point=self.Point(point[0],point[1])
```

Comment: Fix your indentation to match your actual code.